# Should I use react-native-web to convert a React-native app to a web app or implement it from scratch on React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, navigator, react-native-web

I couldn't find a deep comparison between developing a new web application VS refactoring an existing react native source code using react-native-web or expo. (For creating new Web App based on react native app source code).

Our team developed react native app related to the transportation industry which means that there is a great deal of using maps and location features but nor many native mobile features.

Can anyone give me some advice for transforming a react native mobile app into a web application?